# How do I get the OverloadedStrings language extension working?

Tags: haskell, ghc, overloaded-strings

I've enabled overloaded strings, but I can't get them to work:

```
$ cat overloadedstrings.hs 
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

lazy :: BL.ByteString
lazy = "I'm a lazy ByteString"

strict :: B.ByteString
strict = "I'm a strict ByteString"

$ ghci
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l overloadedstrings.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( overloadedstrings.hs, interpreted )

overloadedstrings.hs:7:7:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString BL.ByteString)
      arising from the literal `"I'm a lazy ByteString"'
                   at overloadedstrings.hs:7:7-29
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Data.String.IsString BL.ByteString)
    In the expression: "I'm a lazy ByteString"
    In the definition of `lazy': lazy = "I'm a lazy ByteString"

overloadedstrings.hs:10:9:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString B.ByteString)
      arising from the literal `"I'm a strict ByteString"'
                   at overloadedstrings.hs:10:9-33
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Data.String.IsString B.ByteString)
    In the expression: "I'm a strict ByteString"
    In the definition of `strict': strict = "I'm a strict ByteString"
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Where do I import the `IsString` instances for `ByteString` from? Shouldn't this happen automatically? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of `bytestring` are you using?

Comment: Although I have a solution now, for the record I have bytestring-0.9.1.5.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to import the `.Char8` modules, such as `Data.ByteString.Char8` and `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`