# Do Haskell imports have side effects?

Tags: haskell

I wrote some code a while ago which uses `OverloadedStrings` to create `ByteString`s from hex-encoded String literals, which it decodes using the functions provided by [`base16-bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base16-bytestring). This worked fine, but it seems I didn't understand it as well as I thought.

The thing that has me completely confused is this. Why does

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString.Base16 ()
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

plaintext = "The message" :: B.ByteString

main = print plaintext
```

compile and run OK, but if I remove the import for `Data.ByteString.Base16` then it fails to compile (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815442/how-do-i-get-the-overloadedstrings-language-extension-working)):

```
test.hs:6:13:
No instance for (Data.String.IsString B.ByteString)
  arising from the literal `"The message"'
```

According to the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Import), an import like this is "useful for only importing instances of typeclasses and nothing else", but as far as I can see, the base16-bytestring source code doesn't define any typeclass instances, just the `encode` and `decode` functions.

How does the import provide the necessary instance of `IsString` for the code to compile?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Haskell, typeclass instances are always exported and imported--you can't hide them. This is usually referred to as the "open world assumption".

This means that typeclass instances are also exported transitively: if you import a library with an instance, it gets exported from your module as well.

In this case, the `IsString` instance is in `Data.ByteString.Char8`, which is imported by `Data.ByteString.Base16`. You should be able to replace your import with:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 ()
```

There is a nice [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728596/explicitly-import-instances) giving some information on the open world assumption, if you're interested.